# Referencing static assets in VueJS Components

Tags: javascript, web-applications, webpack, vue.js

I have a VueJS project (customized from a base "webpack-simple" template provided by vue-cli) with the following folder structure

[image: Project Folder Structure]

I am developing the "clickableimage.vue" component and am having trouble referencing assets like images. Code for the component is given below.

```
<template>
<div id="clickableimagecomponent">

<img :src="imageURL" ></img>
<p>Hello There....</p>

</div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
   return {
    imageURL:"./dist/loading.gif",
    msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
  }
 },

}
</script>
```

I have setup webpack to take build the "clickableimage.js" file and drop it into the "dist" folder.

The problem I am facing is that in the component, when I am using src (without any vue bindings) for the img tag as "./assets/loading.gif" it works.

However, the above code also works, when there is no "loading.gif" file in the dist folder. Debugging the JS in FF shows the following.

[image: JS debug in Firefox]

Clearly the file is being loaded from dist/loading.gif, however, no such file exists in the folder.

[image: Folder Structure]

Am i missing something here? I am unable to trace how the browser is able to load the file. Is VueJS doing any behind the scenes magic??

P.S : Just to be sure, I have opened the URL in an incognito window in FF, just in case the browser might be showing a cached version, but it works there too.

My webpack config is as follows..

[image: Webpack Config]

Comment: If you do something like this `imageURL: require("./dist/loading.gif"),`, would it work then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only brainstorming here... I think it has to do with the Hot Module Reloading not being perfect. If you had it as `"./assets/loading.gif"` then that would match `test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/`, and that should produce a base64 encoded image that gets embedded in the script that it bundles (and not placed in the dist folder). Now perhaps what happened when you changed it to `"./dist/loading.gif"`, is that it still searched for `loading.gif` in the script which in the dev environment might still be available since you initially ran the dev server with `"./assets/loading.gif"`. I'm no expert, but I think the img-loader in your webpack config is taking your `"./dist/loading.gif"` and intelligently finding the image in one of the webpack chunks that was initially built. If you were to start the dev server with `"./dist/loading.gif"`, my guess is it would not work as you initially expected it too.